# Is there a way to use GitLab's predefined variables in a pre_build_script in the config.toml?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, aws-fargate, toml

Is there any way to obtain the value of the predefined variable "CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" to be used in a script defined in the "pre_build_script" section of the gitlab runner config.toml configuration?

I'm implementing GitLab Runners with AWS Fargate, and I need to identify the branch from which the commit originates to define which AWS IAM role to use for deployment.

Is it possible to achieve this? I have tried different ways, such as using the environment in the config.toml or directly referencing it in the script, but the value remains empty.

I am attaching the configuration file config.toml that I am using.

```
[[runners]]
  pre_build_script = '''
    echo "CI_COMMIT_BRANCH: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
    if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "dev" ]]; then
      account_number="$dev_AWS_ACCOUNT"
    elif [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "stg" ]]; then
      account_number="$stg_AWS_ACCOUNT"
    elif [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "main" || "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "master" ]]; then
      account_number="$main_AWS_ACCOUNT"
    else
      echo "The current branch ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH) does not match any of the expected branches for deployment on AWS."
      exit 1
    fi
    echo $account_number
    eval $(aws sts assume-role \
    --role-arn arn:aws:iam::${account_number}:role/assume-role \
    --role-session-name=test \
    --query 'join(``, [`export `, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=`, 
    Credentials.AccessKeyId, ` ; export `, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=`,
    Credentials.SecretAccessKey, `; export `, `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=`,
    Credentials.SessionToken])' \
    --output text) || exit 1
  '''
```

I have tried different ways, such as using the environment in the config.toml or directly referencing it in the script, but the value remains empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the `pre_clone_script`, which is now called `pre_get_sources_script`. Here is a working example which I use myself in a multi-account / multi-repo setup. The role name is static (hardcoded), so you only have to supply the `AWS_ACCOUNT_ID` variable to a job. Note that this is deployed with terraform, so the formatting (escaping variables etc) is a bit different than the `config.toml` itself.

```
runner_worker_gitlab_pipeline = {
    pre_clone_script = <<EOT
    '''
    apk add aws-cli -q
    if [ -z "\$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID" ]
    then
      echo -e "Variable [AWS_ACCOUNT_ID] not set: \x1B[96munauthenticated\x1B[0m"
    else
      echo -e "Variable [AWS_ACCOUNT_ID] equals \$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: \x1B[96massume-role\x1B[0m"
      role_arn="arn:aws:iam::\$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID:role/GitlabRole"
      credentials=\$(aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity \
        --role-arn "\$role_arn" \
        --role-session-name "GitLabRunner-\$CI_PROJECT_ID-\$CI_PIPELINE_ID" \
        --web-identity-token "\$CI_JOB_JWT_V2" \
        --duration-seconds "\$CI_JOB_TIMEOUT" \
        --query 'Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]' \
        --output text)
      status=$?
      if [ \$status -eq 0 ]
      then
        export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=\$(echo \$credentials | awk '{print \$1}')
        export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\$(echo \$credentials | awk '{print \$2}')
        export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=\$(echo \$credentials | awk '{print \$3}')
        echo -e "Assumed role: \x1B[96m\$role_arn\x1B[0m"
      else
        echo -e "Failed to assume role: \x1B[96m\$role_arn\x1B[0m"
        exit 1
      fi
    fi
    '''
    EOT
    
    pre_build_script = <<EOT
    '''
    git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:\$CI_JOB_TOKEN@gitlab.com".insteadOf ssh://git@gitlab.com
    '''
    EOT
  }
```